# Decrypt sound before playing a mp3 file in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

This is a very broad question , can I de-crpypt a streaming file, (assuming that i encrpyting this file on the server side during upload) , in flex before it being processed for playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can process sound bytes before playing. This is example from Adobe documentation:

```
var sourceSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var outputSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.mp3");

sourceSnd.load(urlReq);
sourceSnd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    outputSnd.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound);
    outputSnd.play();
}

function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSnd.extract(bytes, 4096);
    event.data.writeBytes(upOctave(bytes));
}

function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray
{
    var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.position = 0;
    while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
    {
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
        {
            bytes.position += 8;
        }
    }
    return returnBytes;
}
```

Refer [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29).